# Java errors compiling Android ROM on Ubuntu 18.04 - SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007faca85010ea

Tags: java, android, android-source, building, rom

I have an up to date Ubuntu budgie 18.04 as build environment and latest official oracle java JDK/JRE 13 on my system to compile Android using a build script (I am not the dev). I am more often getting Java error when compiling the ROM. Using Java 8 openJDK or official 13 I am getting those error every second build or something like that. Anybody got a clue what the problem is?
Build space has 500GB, swap 32GB, RAM 16GB, ccache 100GB

https://pastebin.com/U9YMKksL

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007faca85010ea, pid=25510, tid=25549
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0+181) (build 9+181-android4685155)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9+181-android4685155, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x96d0ea]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_loop_late(VectorSet&, Node_List&, Node_Stack&)+0x13a
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (or dumping to /home/ryder203/abc/core.25510)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: Have you tried not using ccache? It seems to be buggy in Android: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818571/7401546

Comment: No, but CCACHE_EXEC environment variable is set properly.

Comment: Building with a big ccache like 100GB gives me 35min. build time. Without ccache it's hours.

Comment: I did a build now without ccache, but it took all night ... sigh